# postgresql: extract a single record with all fk references

Tags: sql, postgresql

I work with a large postgresql production database. Occasionally there is a need to debug using actual production data.  Because of the size of the database, it is impractical to transfer an entire dump to our development workstations.

Is there a way, perhaps using the information_schema, to extract a single record, as well as:

- all records referenced by this record, cascaded recursively
- all records that refer to this record (with previous criterion applied to these records as well)

Maybe best illustrated with an example:

If we have the following tables:

People (fk to Addresses)

Addresses (fk to Cities)

Cities

Employees  (fks to Employee_Types, People)

Employee_Types

Say that I want to 'extract' a particular record in the People table.  I would want to get:

(1) the record in People

(2) the record in Addresses referenced by the People record in (1)

(3) the record in Cities referenced by the Addresses record in (2)

(4) any Employees record that refers to the People record in (1)

(5) the Employee_Types records that are referenced by the Employees records found in (4)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Create a transfer table with all the records related to those persons:

```
select 
    c.name as city_name, c.id as city_id,
    a.street, a.zip,
    et.type, et.type_id,
    p.id as people_id, p.name,
    e.id as employee_id, e.people_id as employee_people_id, e.type_id as employee_type_id
into transfer
from People p
inner join Addresses a on p.zip = a.zip
inner join Cities c on a.city_id = c.id
inner join Employees e on p.id = e.people_id
inner join Employee_Type et on et.id = e.type_id
where p.id in (@people_id_1, @people_id_2)
```

Then at the destiny insert into the respective tables with attention to the correct order to avoid foreign key errors:

```
insert into Cities (name, id)
select distinct city_name, city_id
from transfer

insert into Addresses (street, zip)
select distinct street, zip
from transfer

insert into People (id, name)
select distinct people_id, name
from transfer

insert into Employee_Type (type, id)
select distinct type, type_id
from transfer

insert into Employees (id, people_id, type_id)
select distinct employee_id, employee_people_id, employee_type_id
from transfer
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without listing off all tables explicitly?  Ideally I'd be able to do this for a record for any table, with an unknown/variable number of foreign key refs.